# Implementing Cursor Trail Effect on React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web-deployment

I am trying to get more experience by implementing various web visual effects that I've seen online. The one I'm working on is to create a 'cursor trail' effect where the cursor trail is used to reveal a background image. For more context, you can find the inspiration for this effect [here](https://codepen.io/chrisdoble/pen/WQLLVp).

The CodePen that I have linked above contains an HTML file, a CSS file, and a JS file. For starters, I am trying to transfer this functionality into a simple React app. To do this, I first initialized a basic/vanilla react app:

```
npx create-react-app cursor_trails_effect
```

I'm having trouble incorporating this cursor trails effect into my React app. From the CodePen, I'm easily able to integrate the HTML and CSS parts into my React app, but am unsure how to connect to and execute the JS script that is part. Yet it makes me wonder, in general, how someone should go about integrating such a JS script into the React framework of web development?

Prior to posting this question, I conducted considerable research to understand how to execute scripts from external (.js) files, or use the `<script>` tag in React, and have tried to use a number of packages that claim to accomplish this (such as `'react-load-script'`, `'react-render-html'`, `'react-script-tag'`, `'dangerously-set-inner-html'`, `'react-helmet'`) but to no success.